# Why is that JAR missing for m2e, but not for Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have a problem that only I have, my colleagues don't have it. So obviously it's not related to the normal Maven build (which works on my machine) and it's not related to our Nexus repository.

In every project that I open which has a dependency to our `util-io`, I get the error message in Eclipse

> Missing artifact ch.ipi:util-io:jar:1.16.0-SNAPSHOT

In the m2e Maven log, I see the following:

> [WARN] The POM for ch.ipi:util-io:jar:1.16.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Now, I tried cleaning my local repo (that is, removing `util-io`), but that didn't help. I'm sure that a new installation of Eclipse would help, but with all the configuration, it takes too long.

As mentioned, if I build the project with the Maven CLI, it works without a problem. So somehow the communication between Nexus, m2e and its index must be wrong.

Here's the directory listing of my local repo:

```
C:\jp\maven-repository\ch\ipi\util-io\1.16.0-SNAPSHOT>dir
m2e-lastUpdated.properties
maven-metadata-repository.central.xml
maven-metadata-repository.central.xml.sha1
resolver-status.properties
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.134029-102-sources.jar
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.134029-102-sources.jar.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.134029-102.jar
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.134029-102.jar.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.134029-102.pom
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.134029-102.pom.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.180430-103.jar
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.180430-103.jar.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.180430-103.pom
util-io-1.16.0-20140320.180430-103.pom.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140323.180440-107.jar
util-io-1.16.0-20140323.180440-107.jar.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140323.180440-107.pom
util-io-1.16.0-20140323.180440-107.pom.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.103410-108.jar
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.103410-108.jar.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.103410-108.pom
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.103410-108.pom.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.123208-109.jar
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.123208-109.jar.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.123208-109.pom
util-io-1.16.0-20140324.123208-109.pom.sha1
util-io-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
util-io-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
util-io-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
_maven.repositories
```

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using m2e with the embedded or external maven installation?

Comment: I'm using an external Maven installation.

Comment: Since `C:\jp\maven-repository` isn't where maven would normally look for your repository, is Eclipse m2e using the same settings.xml as command-line mvn? In Eclipse, check if Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installation matches your command-line environment.

Comment: Yes, the `settings.xml` has been configured to use that directory and Eclipse is using it.